# phablet-tools download problem

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have Ubuntu 12 i386 running great from a 16 gig flash drive. I'm trying to get the `sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot` command to work. Everything downloads fine save for the phablet-tools. it says the pacage contains unmet dependencies and is not installable? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After adding:

```
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ raring main universe
```

from

[http://packages.ubuntu.com/us/raring/i386/python-lzma/download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/raring/i386/python-lzma/download)

it worked for me.

Hope it helps you, too.